# How exactly does the snapshot listener metric in Firestore work?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

[image: Here's what I see in my Firestore usage dashboard for snapshot listeners]

I am building a flutter app, and I am using a stream to subscribe to Firestore query results. Unfortunately, I don't understand how the snapshot listener metric works, combined with this tidbit from the documentation:

[image: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#realtime_updates]

Does the 27 peak mean I've somehow created 27 listeners (when I should be making one)? I'm confused.

Also to note that I have made 0 interactions with my app, just left it running..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Firestore, every time you add the `onSnapshot` method, you're creating a new Snapshot Listener for this user.
So according to you print, you have 1 user connected to your app (1 Active Connection) and this user has 27 listeners attached to it.
So it seems that either you're getting real time updates from 27 Firestore queries, or you're not closing your connections.

From the 3rd reference, from Firebase docs:

> Let's say a user opens your app on their phone. The app then connects to Cloud Firestore and subscribes to 10 queries. This increases your metrics by 1 active connection and 10 snapshot listeners.

### Is it bad?

Even though you're not paying for those active connection or the listeners, every time a doc is read / updated, this will count as a new read, and those are charged in the end. So using way too many listeners is not the best practice.

### What to do?

The first thing I'd say is to double check if you're not keeping the listeners opened once the component / view is closed.
If you find any, [don't forget to detach them.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#node.js_5)

### References

- [1][Firebase description for listeners pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens)
- [2][Detaching a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#node.js_5)
- [3][Cloud monitoring Dashboard explanation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage#cloud-monitoring)

Comment: Thanks! One follow up question after doing some diving into my code -

Comment: @user1354934 the number of listeners is only related to the app connected and its logic on creating the listeners.
If the user is not using the app, only has one screen opened, and still you have all of those connected, than you'd need to review it, and start detaching them.

Comment: Now if you need to make 1 or more, is related to your app's logic, and you only can tell. 
But here an example: if I have a food delivering app, is it really needed to have a listeners for available recipes? Or every time the user gets into the menu it you get a new update on the list?
Now for the restaurant, is it needed a listeners to update orders received? I'd say that's a definitely yes, as they might miss orders if don't update the page constantly.

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry it seems I pressed enter too fast and lost all my message :(

In my case I am showing users which virtual parties are still open to join and I need it to be real time. I am going back to review my codes :( but I think I will figure it out thanks to your help :D

Comment: Glad to hear I could help you!